# How to compare different ratings of different products by different customers

Tags: ranking

I have ratings of different products (a number, 1...10) by different customers in different countries.

Product X will get a high rating in country A. Product Y will get a medium rating in country B. However, both customers are happy with the product.

Is there a way to make the rating fairer? For example, if people in country A are more likely to rate products with a ten, a ten is less valuable than in country B, where people consider a rating of seven very good. In country B, getting a ten is excellent.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! It is probably helpful to be more specific about your end goal with these ratings. E.g., is this a measurement (e.g., you want to assess customer satisfaction as well as possible, and/or quantify uncertainty) or prediction problem (e.g., you want to predict the ratings of customers using other variables, or you want to predict other variables using the ratings of customers)? And perhaps provide more details about data structure (e.g., approximate number of products, costumers, countries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways of dealing with it. These include:

- Random effects models: If you write down a regression model (e.g. treating the score as a continuous outcome possibly with some transformation, or as an ordinal one in an ordinal logistic regression), you can specify a rater-random-effect on the intercept. In contrast, the product could have a fixed effect. E.g. to use R syntax something like `rating ~  0 + product + (1|rater)` (where rater and product as factors).
- In the above you would probably want to make the rater effect on the intercept random, because many raters will have very few ratings. If all raters have a lot of ratings, one could of course make rater a fixed main effect.
- The converse applies to products: If some products have hardly any ratings, you could add a random product effect on the intercept. That helps initially when products are still mostly unrated, and the influence reduces as more an more ratings become available.
- If you think that some countries just tend to give lower ratings, you could of course have a country effect in such a model (or a random country effect on the intercept, in case some countries give very little data). Similarly, if some countries like some specific products (or product categories) more or less, that could be reflected through country by product or country by product-category interactions.
- A recommender system approach, e.g. using a neural network with both product and rater embeddings (e.g. combining ideas from [here](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/08_collab.ipynb) and [here](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/09_tabular.ipynb), [here](https://twitter.com/jeremyphoward/status/1514455555741401088?s=03) and [here](https://twitter.com/radekosmulski/status/1531523922713116673?t=I0GfermRXGzLtFV2IDH8wQ&s=03)). The main challenge would just be to produce a rating for an average customer (or completely new customer, which is difficult due to the cold-start problem), because the product embeddings would not necessarily have a direct single "higher is better"-dimension. I think there's some solutions like enforcing that previously unknown customers have an all-zero embedding so that you could output ratings with that. Otherwise, a lot of the same ideas as above (like the possibility to also add country embeddings) apply, although interactions would be implicitly present.

There's a lot of connections here to item response theory (IRT), which is usually about different items on questionnaires being differently hard, forms of multiple-rater-multiple-case studies, and recommender systems.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to this extensive answer. I will look into it and try to apply your ideas.